# An optimum HTTP error code for process not running?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

I am in process of building a rest server, which will be called to abort a long running process by client.

`/abort/{processID}`

Now if process with processID is not found, I am returning `404 Not Found`

However if the process has already been completed/is not running, then what shall be correct HTTP Error code for the same?

`406 Not Acceptable` is relevant to Accept header (and hence I think I shall not used).

`400 Bad Request` appears to be too generic.

Seeking suggestions on which header will be optimum for it?

Comment: I'd use 422 or 403.

Comment: Thanks @SergioTulentsev However as I see 403 is related to credentials issue (user authenticated but not authorized) and since there is no body in my request, I am not sure if 403 fits in.

Can 410 be used?

Comment: How about 410 - Gone?

Comment: @Optional: yeah, maybe not 403 then :)

Comment: 410 is an option but IMO you should stick to 404 because (1) is there any reason for the client to know the difference? and (2) this might be a security issue depending on what exactly happens under the resource.

Comment: @freakish It is to let client know that, processID, they have passed is still valid, and the history of process did exist. If process is completed, he can go and fetchResult for the processID. Giving 404, will freak them, as if they have got wrong ID. 

Interesting to read was you said a "security" issue. Wondering how it could be for secured services.

Comment: @Optional Is the client typing the id? Or does it get it from the server anyway? If the id comes directly from the client then I suppose you are right. But otherwise there is no point in doing that since you can send the status of the process together with the id. As for the security: usually you want to reduce the amount of information you give to the user to the absolute minimum. Otherwise a hacker may find a backdoor to your system.

Comment: If the process no longer exists, consider `404` or `410`, depending on whether the condition is permanent or not. If a process can be found with a given id, but the attempt to abort this process cannot be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the process, you could go for a `409`. If the operation is forbidden for other reasons, choose `403`. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46154695/1426227) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Here are some reasonable options that may suit you:

- `404` Not Found
- `410` Gone
- `409` Conflict
- `403` Forbidden

The right choice relies on the semantics of *process has already been completed/is not running*:

- If the process no longer exists, consider `404` or `410`, depending on whether the condition is permanent or not.
- If a process can be found with a given id, but the attempt to abort this process cannot be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the process, you could go for `409`.
- If the operation is forbidden for other reasons, choose `403`.

### The process no longer exists

If the process no longer exists, you could choose between `404` and `410`, depending on whether the condition is (or it is possible to determine whether the condition is) permanent or not.

See the following quotes from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.4.  404 Not Found**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.4)
>
> The `404` (Not Found) status code indicates that the origin server
> did not find a current representation for the target resource or is
> not willing to disclose that one exists.  A `404` status code does
> not indicate whether this lack of representation is temporary or
> permanent; the `410` (Gone) status code is preferred over `404` if the
> origin server knows, presumably through some configurable means, that
> the condition is likely to be permanent. [...]

> [**6.5.9.  410 Gone**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.9)
>
> The `410` (Gone) status code indicates that access to the target
> resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this
> condition is likely to be permanent.  If the origin server does not
> know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not the condition
> is permanent, the status code `404` (Not Found) ought to be used
> instead. [...]

### The process exists, but the operation causes a conflict

If the process exists, `404` or `410` are not the good choices.

If the attempt to abort an existing process cannot be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the process, you should consider `409` along with a payload that describes the reason of the conflict.

See the quote:

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]

### The process exists, but the operation is forbidden for some reason

One last option is `403`. This status code is frequently used for *authorization* problems, when the credentials are valid, but they are insufficient to authorize the request.

However `403` is much broader than that and could be used to indicate that a request is forbidden for reasons *unrelated to the credentials*. Just be sure you provide a payload that describes *why* the operation is forbidden.

See the quote:

> [**6.5.3.  403 Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)
>
> The `403` (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood
> the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to
> make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that
> reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the
> server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client
> SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same
> credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different
> credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons
> unrelated to the credentials.
>
> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a
> forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of
> `404` (Not Found).

Comment: I'd argue that 403 were more of a stretch than 409, with latter one directly referring to the current state of a resource. Solid answer nonetheless.